# dual value of a linear constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Assume a minimization problem.

The dual of an inequality '<' constraint is the marginal improvement in the objective function (ie marginal reduction) by marginally increasing the right-hand-side of the constraint. Is this correct?

The dual of an equality '=' constraint is the marginal improvement in the objective function (ie marginal reduction) by marginally increasing the right-hand-side of the constraint. Is this correct?

The dual of an inequality '>' constraint is the marginal improvement in the objective function (ie marginal reduction) by marginally increasing the right-hand-side of the constraint. Is this correct?

Comment: Could you give us a numerical example to make clear, what do you mean ?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a consistent convention. I can tell you that for inequalities, I always assume a *nonnegative* dual variable. That necessarily means that < and > inequalities have a different interpretation in the dual.

Comment: @MichaelGrant  

If we want to minimize cost,and we have a constraint that says x<= A , the dual of this constraint means how much the objective will reduce by increasing the A marginally. Correct?

But if we have x = A constraint, then what does its dual indicate?

Comment: Well, for equality constraints, there is no certainty. It depends on exactly how the dual problem was constructed. If your Lagrangian term is $\lambda^T(x-A)$, you'll get the negative of the dual cost compared to using $\lambda^T(A-x)$. Both are valid. The convention chosen is going to depend on the specific solver you use, and you're going to have to figure that out from the documentation for that solver---or you'll have to try it and see.